# How to apply texture to the material from script editor in the Spark AR

Tags: javascript, textures, augmented-reality, patch, spark-ar-studio

I just want to recreate this kind of connections from the patch editor. Old API not support() but library not update too... So, I can't understand how to apply the 'cameraTexture' to the .DIFFUSE attribute of the material.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to set the Material texture through script? In that case you can just simply set the Material.diffuse property on the material to the texture you want to use.

See the documentation here: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/materialsmodule.materialbase

[image]

Comment: Im try you example and it's work. But, this only works when I just try to assign texture to the material. When im try to define UV for TextureSampler my VS Code marking this line of code: const uv = Shaders.vertexAttribute({'variableName':Shaders.VertexAttribute.POSITION});   Property 'VertexAttribute' does not exist on type 'typeof ShadersModule'. Did you mean 'vertexAttribute'?  - I tried everything but to no avail. This error similar to that with (Shaders.DefaultMaterialTextures.DIFFUSE) where VS Code marking "DefaultMaterialTextures". I script correctly. Why does he give an error?